# PHP auto login and redirect using curl

Tags: php, redirect, curl, cookies

I am trying to auto login to a site and redirect. I am doing this using curl here is my code but its not working for me I mean its not doing auto login even my login details are correct I can login directly but can't through curl php.
Here is my code:

```
function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt","w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($login);
    unset($login);

    }
function grab_page($site){
    $ch= curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,40);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
        }
function post_data($site,$data){
    $datapost = curl_init();
    $headers=array("Expect:");
    curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_URL,$site);
    curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,40000);
    curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_HEADER,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($datapost,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec($datapost);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($datapost);
    unset($datapost);

    }
echo login("https://www.jollywallet.com/api/aff","token=00D3A9E8-A9F4-F21B-122E-54AF4B00A0E8&captcha%5Binput%5D=&captcha%5Bid%5D=&type=login&user=armokoj@gmail.com&dist_id=0&dist_sub_id=0&password=4704e86d0ea8a20752a9b882b9a2a5f9&reg_option=2");

echo grab_page("https://www.jollywallet.com/jollywallet/storelist");
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't explain what is your error.

if you are login and get right response from server but web redirect or use another curl to go to another page but response of second curl is login page its back to your cookie. yes I know you save cookie but some site use a javascript to set cookie then must browser load the page to get right cookie or other thing that cause cookie is not work well

if your first curl that use to login back a wrong response then you don't send some data. some site use hidden input must send them and in some case value of that hidden input fill with javascript and you must fill it yourself

I hope this help you